# Google Apps Script DriveApp folder methods broken

Tags: google-apps-script

The following script runs until it hits the Script runtime limit:

```
function myFunction() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('****************************');
}
```

> Exceeded maximum execution time

Execution transcript:

```
[17-10-02 13:19:52:078 PDT] Starting execution
[17-10-02 13:27:10:799 PDT] DriveApp.getFolderById([0B3a2JcvKU7xEbkdlVk11LXZ1M1E]) [438.713 seconds]
[17-10-02 13:27:10:811 PDT] Execution failed: Server error occurred, please try again. (line 2, file "Kod") [438.715 seconds total runtime]
```

The same script on a different G Suite domain works fine.

There are a couple of open issues on the Issue Tracker but they are not much starred so I assume only a limited number of domains are affected.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67054694

I have several scripts in production that depends on these methods so this is a serious issue for me.

Comment: I've see some weird problems occasionally and I've tried many things to overcome them.  Sometimes shutting down my browser and some times deleting a spreadsheet and starting another.  Clearly this function has to work or we'd all be having significant problems.  I think it has to be something in your environment and probably something that you have no control over.

Comment: There is also a post in the Apps Script community about this: [Link to Apps Script community - Drive issue in paid accounts](https://plus.google.com/104133407173191880175/posts/f1g8nGn767k)

Comment: Thanks @SandyGood, I commented in that thread.

Comment: @Cooper I'm aware of that this kind of post is not what SO was built for. The issue is most certainly a bug and I'm just trying to get some attention. Since G Suite support is very reluctant to deal with GAS issues SO and the Issue Tracker are basically the only ways to reach Google. Hopefully someone experiencing this same problem is starring the issue I referred to on Issue Tracker. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oct 5, 2017 Google added a comment:

> This should be resolved now. Please let us know if you're continuing
>   to see errors.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67054694